# Unable to Understand the Abel's Theorem for Elliptic Functions

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, differential-geometry, elliptic-functions

**Definition:** Let $f$ be an elliptic function on $\mathbb{C}$ and $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ be the periodic lattice of $f$. The divisior of $f$ is defined as $$(f)=\sum_j n_jP_j$$
where $P_j$ are the zeros/poles of $f$ on $T=\mathbb{C}/\Omega$ with mutiplicities $n_j$.

The degree of the divisor is defined as
$$deg(f)=\sum_j n_j$$

**Theorem: (Abel)** There exists some elliptic function $f$ on $\mathbb{C}/\Omega$ with divisor $$\sum_j n_jP_j$$
iff

$(1) \sum_j n_j=0$

$(2) \sum_j n_jP_j \in \Omega$

I can't quite understand the statement $(1)$ above  because doesn't it imply that $n_j=0 \forall j$?

Comment: The (non-constant) function will have poles ($n_j <0$) and zeros ($n_j>0 $). Namely, the multiplicity is signed. For a non-elliptic example, on the riemann sphere, the divisor of the poly $(z-5)(z-7)$ is $(5) +(7) - 2(\infty)$, and the sum of the $n_j$ is zero. General fact: the sum of the coefficients of a divisor is called the degree, and the degree of the divisor of a rational function is always zero, for any rational function on any (compact) Riemann surface.

Comment: Sorry - I hadn't noticed that you had defined 'degree' already. And 'rational function' can be replaced by 'meromorphic function' in my previous....